# How to bypass/authorize ADB RSA key with broken touch AND screen?

Tags: adb, broken-screen

I've tried everything I could find on the internet (mostly on *StackOverflow*).

These I've already tried without result:

1. [*Page not found - Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082608/is-it-possible-to-authorize-adb-on-my-android-phone-with-a-broken-screen)
2. [shell - How to solve ADB device unauthorized in Android ADB host device? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device)
3. [android - running adb devices showing unauthorized device? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236960/running-adb-devices-showing-unauthorized-device)

**Both screen AND touch are broken so I can't see nor touch a thing.** (So the OTG mouse option can't be used in my case.)

The device is a *Huawei Ascend P7 L10, Lollipop 5.1.1.*

- It's rooted.
- It has TWRP recovery.
- USB Debugging is enabled.
- I'm using the latest ADB version, updated from Android Studio.

I entered recovery mode, done `adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys` and rebooted, after reboot adb keeps saying devices isn't authorized.
I entered recovery checked if the file copied on the device was still the same as the one in the *.android* folder, and it was the same key.

If anybody has any idea I'm all ears. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/bypass-secure-usb-debugging-prompt-t2965462 this is the solution.

Comment: I was in a very similar situation to what you are in. What worked for me was using `/sbin/adb` instead of the one provided by Android Studio.

Comment: @NeilAgarwal you might want to convert your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I could find is for you to use *adb kill-server* and check again with *adb devices.* You seem to have done everything you can. :(

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try SCRCPY module which will give you the access to your screen and you can do all the things from the PC

Which device??

Comment: Scrcpy also needs adb which in turn would need rsa authentication.